Why bottom toolbar items placement is changing when i apply toolbar color scheme modifier in SwiftUI?
So when there is more than 2 toolbar items the default item placement is all the items (ToolbarItem) in the hierarchy to the left and the last item (ToolbarItem) in the hierarchy to the right.
After i apply .toolbarColorScheme(.light, for: .bottomBar) or .toolbarColorScheme(.dark, for: .bottomBar) modifier, and scroll all the way to the bottom, the 2nd item also goes to the right side.
//
//  ToolbarGlitchDemo.swift
//  ToolbarGlitchDemo
//
//  Created by rayhaanlykhan on 15/04/2024.
//

import SwiftUI

struct ToolbarGlitchDemo: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationStack {
            
            ZStack {
                
                Color.gray.ignoresSafeArea()
                
                ScrollView {
                    
                    ForEach(0..<15) { _ in
                        
                        Rectangle()
                            .fill(.blue)
                            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Toolbar Glitch Demo")
            
            .toolbar {
                                
                ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) { // center
                    
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "scribble")
                        Image(systemName: "gear")
                    }
                    .background(.yellow)
                }
                
                ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
                    
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "person.fill")
                    }
                    .background(.red)
                }
                
                ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
                    
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "person")
                        Image(systemName: "person")
                    }
                    .background(.green)
                }
            }
            .toolbarColorScheme(.light, for: .bottomBar)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ToolbarGlitchDemo()
}


Checked on iOS 17.3.1 and 17.4

Interesting! Since all 3 ToolbarItem are being given placement .bottomBar, the actual positions within the bottom bar are probably undefined.
I discovered than when you add the images individually (in other words, as 5 ToolbarItem)  then it starts off as 4+1 and switches to 1+4 when you scroll to the bottom -> also inconsistent.
You can fix by setting one single ToolbarItem consisting of an HStack where you define the spacing:
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
        HStack {
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "scribble")
                Image(systemName: "gear")
            }
            .background(.yellow)

            Spacer()

            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "person.fill")
            }
            .background(.red)

            Spacer()

            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "person")
                Image(systemName: "person")
            }
            .background(.green)
        }
    }
}
.toolbarColorScheme(.light, for: .bottomBar)


I wonder why this glitch only occurs when we put '.toolbarColorScheme' modifier.

@RehanAliKhan Yes, it's an odd one. I don't suppose it's by design. But then again, when three toolbar items are given the same toolbar position, it's maybe not surprising that the result is unpredictable.
